# IOS - Get Current TimeZone of Device in GMT format

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone, gmt

I have searched a lot Regarding this issue on Google but Did,t find Proper Solution. All Result Gives Timezone in Date and time format.

I want to Know that How to get Only Timezone of Device in GMT Format.
Like, I want only this

> +5:30

as TimeZone. How can i achive  this ?

I have tried this

```
 NSTimeZone* currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

but it will give result in kolkatta/Delhi . 
I have also tried other answer but didn't find solution.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to look at Apple Documentation for [`NSTimeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/).

If you do, you became aware that there is a method `-secondsFromGMT` that returns seconds form the Greenwich time.
Maybe you can also create your own [date formatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) string to pass as `-dateFormat` property of an `NSDateFormatter` and get directly a string representation of time zone. Something like that `@"ZZZZZ"`.
Click [**here**](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for info on how to code correctly a date format.

Comment: Creating a date formatter that only returns the offset from GMT sounds like the correct solution. (voted.) That way you don't have to worry about fussy formatting issues. The date formatter would do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
    NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ZZZ"];

     NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName: @"Asia/Kolkata"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: myDate];
    NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

**OUTPUT:**

+0530

For more information read the @Andrea answer

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)getCurrentTimeZoneMins
{
    NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    float timeZoneOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:[NSDate date]] / 60;;
    NSLog(@"%f mins",timeZoneOffset);
}

-(void)printTimeZone
{
    NSDateFormatter *localTimeZoneFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    localTimeZoneFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    localTimeZoneFormatter.dateFormat = @"Z";
    NSString *localTimeZoneOffset = [localTimeZoneFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"%@",localTimeZoneOffset);
}
```